# Pattern Programming using for loops

Tags: c

with the code I've written below, I'm able to print the following pattern:

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int no_rows, rows, column;
  printf("Please enter a value: ");
  scanf("%d", &no_rows);

  for( rows = no_rows; rows >= 1; rows--) {
    for(column = 1; column <= rows; column++) {
      printf("* "); 
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

So the question is, how can I manipulate my code, so that I can print out the following pattern?

[image]

Comment: print 0 `' '`, print 6 `'*'`.  --- print 1 `' '`, print 5 `'*'`.  --- print 2 `' '`, print 4 `'*'`... etc (Hint, requires 2 loops nested inside the outer loop)

Comment: Please confirm that you can print the first pattern including the empty places. The grid you show (which I am sure you do not print) implies it. But in that case you would probably not ask....

Comment: @byxor I think two loops are not required, a single inner loop with a conditional is the alternative.

Comment: @Yunnosch Right – but the conditional needs to be checked within every loop run while with two loops only the end condition needs to be checked – so I'd at least prefer the two ones.

Comment: Side note: Though not mattering in given case the more typical kind of iterating in C is rather `for(column = 0; column < rows; column++)` – especially relevant if iterating over arrays (alike in C++ if you might ever switch to).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is just to first print the preceding spaces, and only then the asterisks - so first print row spaces, and only then print the remaining asterisks:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void print_pattern(const size_t no_rows)
{
    size_t rows = 0, column = 0;

    for (rows = 0; rows < no_rows; rows += 1)
    {
        for (column = 0; column < rows; column += 1)
        {
            printf("  ");
        }

        for (; column < no_rows; column += 1)
        {
            printf(" *");
        }
        
        puts("");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t no_rows = 0;

    printf("Please enter a value: ");
    scanf("%lu", &no_rows);

    print_pattern(no_rows);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Little bit more mathematical approach:

```
char triangle(int x, int y)
{
     return x >= y ? '*' : ' ';
}
    
void print_pattern(int size)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            printf("%c ", triangle(x, y));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

If more flexibility is needed, you can add a function pointer argument to `print_pattern`. With some other modifications, calling code could be something like this:

```
scanf("%d", &size);
print_pattern(size, triangle);
print_pattern(size, sphere);
```